# Trying to plot Open Interest from COT report on quantmod chart

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I am trying to load the COT(commitment of traders report) into a xts object, so I can plot it on a graph with different symbols.

I have this data:

```
           OI      Smart_Long  Smart_Short Comm_Long Comm_Short
2013-01-08 227030      67302       75623     88628      77408
2013-01-15 255620      79789       73214     89670     100277
2013-01-22 260817      83253       62843     92014     115104
2013-01-29 294272      91088       67119    105281     130716
2013-02-05 325352      91454       60687    122242     151926
2013-02-12 286854      85577       61319    108681     139583
2013-02-19 282781      79810       59322    107203     133294
```

(http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5Y9nV0Us)

And this R code:

```
########################################
#Get the data
setInternet2(TRUE)
con = gzcon(url('http://www.systematicportfolio.com/sit.gz', 'rb'))
    source(con)
close(con)

library(quantmod)
EURUSD = getSymbols.fxhistoricaldata('EURUSD', 'hour', auto.assign = F, download=T)
EURO_cot <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5Y9nV0Us",header=F,sep=",")

###########################################
#Format the data
EURO_dates <- as.POSIXlt(EURO_cot[,3])
EURO_cot <- EURO_cot[,c(8,9,10,12,13)]

headers2<- c("OI", 
"Smart_Long", "Smart_Short", 
"Comm_Long", "Comm_Short")
colnames(EURO_cot) <- headers2
EURO_xts <- as.xts(EURO_cot, EURO_dates)
###########################################
#Plot the data
chartSeries(to.weekly(EURUSD[,1]['2013-01-01::2013-02-16']))
addTA(EURO_xts[,1]['2013-01-01::2013-02-16'])

Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(tav * 0.975, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(tav * 1.05, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Thanks for all the help you can provide!

PS. the raw cot data can be downloaded from here,
http://www.cftc.gov/MarketReports/CommitmentsofTraders/HistoricalCompressed/index.htm

under the *Futures-and-Options Combined Reports:* section

Comment: Please provide the output from `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: `getSymbols.fxhistoricaldata`! is it a custom function? and under the *Futures-and-Options Combined Reports: section* there aree many reports can you precise which one?

Comment: getSymbols.fxhistoricaldata is implemented by SystematicPortfolio. You can choose any of the Text files... If you want them you have to extract the rows you want, I have already uploaded the relevant rows to pastebin.com

Comment: Output from sessionInfo() `C_COLLATE=Norwegian (Bokmål)_Norway.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Norwegian (Bokmål)_Norway.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Norwegian (Bokmål)_Norway.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Norwegian (Bokmål)_Norway.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4-0 TTR_0.21-1     xts_0.9-3      zoo_1.7-9      Defaults_1.1-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.2     lattice_0.20-10`

Comment: Okay, I added the to.weekly command in the second last line, and it dosnt give a error, but it does not draw my line... How can I draw a bar plot in a chartSeries? (the COT data comes out every friday, aka weekly data, while my candle data is daily)